# Memory allocation function based on chunks

Tags: c++, search

I have to create a memory allocation program that is supposed to allocate memory blocks to a memory that contains 8 contiguous memory positions. N is the size of the memory, M is the maximum number of positions a program can request and X is the number of memory positions requested. The memory is divided in M chunks, each equally made of N/M memory positions. N/M must be greater than M, otherwise a program will not have enough memory allocated to a chunk. The first element of POS stores the position (in the memory) where the first available block of 1 memory position is located, the second element stores the position (in memory) where the first available block of 2 memory positions is located and so on. If the ith element in the array POS stores number -1, it means that there are no blocks of (i+1) memory positions available in the ith chunk. If POS[X-1] stores a value different from -1, it means there is space to allocate a block of X. In that case, the value stored in POS[X-1] is returned. Otherwise, the value -1 is returned.

From what I understand of the question, it wants me to create a memory allocation program that separates 8 memory positions into chunks. Each chunk is required to be about as big as M, which is the largest number of memory positions a program can request. So M is 3 in the question so each chunk should be about 3 memory positions, meaning two chunks of 3 and one chunk of 2. Now the first chunk is allocated only for requests that only need 1 memory position, second chunk for requests that need 2 contiguous memory positions and third chunk for requests that need 3 memory positions. [Example using 16 memory positions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1WEV.jpg). Here's what I have so far.

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
  
int search(int arr[], int n, int m, int x) 
{ 
    int POS[m];
    
    if(POS[x-1]!=-1){
        return POS[x-1];
    } return -1;
} 
  
int main(void) 
{ 
    int arr[] = { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 }; //example array, -1 represents available memory space
    int x = 2; //example number of memory positions requested 
    int n = sizeof(arr) /sizeof(arr[0]); //size of array
    int m = 3; //maximum number of positions a program can request
    
    int result = search(arr, n, m, x); 
    if(result == -1) {
        cout << "No slots available"; 
    } else { 
        cout << x << " slots available at index " << result;; 
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to get your nomenclature straight - until you do, your description is ambiguous to a human (which means there is no way to translate it into code that can be understood by a computer - which is essentially an ignoramus that requires pedantically unambiguous instructions to function correctly).   For example, when you say "8-byte memory", do you mean that *addresses* are stored in 8 bytes?  If you are also assuming that a byte consists of 8 bits (which is NOT guaranteed by the standard) this is more conventionally referred to as 64-bit memory.

Comment: @Peter in this context, it means 8 contiguous memory positions. I'm not sure but which other terms are ambiguous?

Answer (score 0):

To rephrase a little, it sounds like your question is essentially that there is an array of N ints where `-1` represents an "available" element, and the goal is to find the position of X contiguous available element. I'm ignoring M and the POS array.

In other words, find a run of X or more -1 values. Here is an outline to do that with an O(N) search:

1. Initialize `count` to zero.
2. Make a loop, for i = 0, 1, ..., N - 1:

   - If `arr[i]` is available, increment the count. If the count is now equal to X, return `(i - X)` as the starting position of the X contiguous available elements.
   - Otherwise, reset the count to zero.

---

**Edit:** Based on your comment and [example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1WEV.jpg), it sounds like the point of M-sized chunks is that each chunk of memory may contain only one allocation. This approach of course wastes some elements when allocations are smaller than M, but does make the allocation search easier.

Outline:

- For each chunk...

  - Check whether the first `arr` element of the chunk is unused. If it so, then the whole chunk is available by the "one allocation per chunk" assumption.
  - To cover an edge case, if this is the last chunk, check that its size is at least X.
  - If both of these conditions are true, return the current chunk.

Comment: From what I understand of the question, it wants me to create a memory allocation program that separates 8 memory positions into chunks. Each chunk is required to be about as big as M, which is the largest number of memory positions a program can request. So M is 3 in the question so each chunk should be about 3 memory positions, meaning two chunks of 3 and one chunk of 2. Now the first chunk is allocated only for 1 memory position blocks, second chunk for 2 contiguous memory blocks and third chunk for 3 contiguous memory blocks. [Example using 16 memory positions](https://imgur.com/a/D5pd0Pf)

Comment: Thanks for that clarification. So IIUC each chunk may contain only one allocation? Please see the edit on my answer above.

Comment: Do you know what it means by this part? If the i-th element in the array POS stores number -1, it means that there are no blocks of (i+1) memory positions available in the i-th chunk.

Comment: Sorry, there are a lot of details here. I didn't follow how POS is relevant to the question. In your posted code, POS is an uninitialized array local to the `search()` function. Should POS be an input to `search()`? Or is `search()` supposed to produce POS as an output? I suggest editing your post to clarify what the question statement is, and separate that distinctly from description of your progress on a solution.